# Mysql regex to match a string in string

Tags: sql, regex

I am trying to work out a regex in sql to match the following condition

value = 'AA,XX | BB,XX | CC,XX | DD,XX', which is separated by '|'

search = 'B,XX' => false

search = 'A,XX' => false

search = 'BB,XX' => true

search = 'AA,XX' => true

if chosen to use %search% then 'B,XX', 'A,XX' will also match the pattern

Would someone provide some guidance for a nest regex for this matter

Kindly Regards

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. Are you looking to match `AA` or `BB`? If so, have you tried using `OR`? Are you looking to match them both? If it's both, have you tried using `AND`? Are you looking to match the entire pattern? It's unclear if you need a regex or if you simply need a SQL tutorial or book. Can you [edit] your question to make it more clear what you're asking?

Comment: As I mentioned, either AA, BB, CC or DD should return 1
but not A nor B nor any partial matching

Comment: I'm sorry. Your comment doesn't improve anything, and neither does your minimal edit.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is the function `find_in_set()`.  However, you need to change the separators to commas:

```
where find_in_set('B', replace(value, '|', ','))
```

You can also use `like`:

```
where concat('|', value, '|') like concat('%|', 'B', '|%')
```

In both these expressions, `'B'` represents an arbitrary search string.

Comment: You may have correctly guessed at this poster's intent, but you've removed all incentive for the OP to edit to improve it so that it's useful to future readers. (Not downvoting; just pointing it out.)

Comment: @KenWhite . . . I actually found the question quite understandable.